# My WPForms doesn't work. I'm working with sendinblue

Tags: wordpress, smtp, wpforms

Hey I'm trying to work with sendinblue and I need help because I don't know how to work with it.
Can anyone help me? Thanks

I'm struggling to use sendinblue services

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation about the usage of WPForms with Sendinblue is available on the WPForms.com site for the Sendinblue add-on: https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-install-and-use-the-sendinblue-addon-with-wpforms/